# BVP with 2nd order coupled ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I get the following [error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYV5M.png):

- Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
- Indeterminate expression 0.\ ComplexInfinity encountered.
- Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at s == 0.1

*Please provide any comments if possible ! Thank you all*

** Kirchoff's equations for a cut circular rod, fixed on one end and load applied on other  **

** Getting the Rotation matrices **

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
R1 = RotationMatrix[-ψ[s], {0, 0, 1}];
R2 = RotationMatrix[-θ[s], {0, 1, 0}];
R3 = RotationMatrix[-ϕ[s], {1, 0, 0}];
```

** Applied force vector in orthonormal frame **

```
Fvec = R3 . R2 . R1 . {F, 0, 0} ;
d1 = FullSimplify[Inverse[R3 . R2 . R1] . {1, 0, 0}];
d2 = FullSimplify[Inverse[R3 . R2 . R1] . {0, 1, 0}];
d3 = FullSimplify[Inverse[R3 . R2 . R1] . {0, 0, 1}];
```

** Getting the curvatures **

```
kn = R3 . R2 . R1 . {-1/R, 0, 0} ;
k = {ϕ'[s] - 
   Sin[θ[s]]*ψ'[s], θ'[s]*Cos[ϕ[s]] + 
   Cos[θ[s]]*Sin[ϕ[s]]*ψ'[s], 
  Sin[ϕ[s]]*(-θ'[s] + 
     Cos[θ[s]]*Cos[ϕ[s]]*ψ'[s])}
```

** Constitutive law **

```
{M1, M2, T} = B*{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, RR}} . (k - kn);
```

** Boundary conditions**

```
startpt = 0.1;
startval = 0.1;
endpt = 1.9 Pi ;
IC1 = ψ[startpt] == startval;
IC2 = θ[startpt] == startval;
IC3 = ϕ[startpt] == startval;
IC5 = FullSimplify[Part[k, 1] - Part[kn, 1]] == startval /. 
    s -> endpt /. R -> 1;
IC4 = FullSimplify[Part[k, 2] - Part[kn, 2]] == startval /. 
    s -> endpt /. R -> 1;
IC6 = FullSimplify[Part[k, 3] - Part[kn, 3]] == startval /. 
    s -> endpt /. R -> 1;
```

** Combining all of above **

```
Mvec = {M1, M2, T} /. R -> 1.0 /. B -> 1000. /. RR -> 2/3;
eqns = FullSimplify[Thread[D[Mvec, s] == -Cross[d3, Fvec]]];
bcs = {IC1, IC2, IC3, IC4, IC5, IC6};
```

** Solving the BVP **

```
solution = Block[{F = 1245}, NDSolve[
   Join[eqns, bcs], {ψ[s], θ[s], ϕ[s]}, {s, startpt, 
    endpt}]]
```

[image: screenshot of error messages]

Comment: With some options in `NDSolve` like  `Method -> 
 "BoundaryValues" -> {"Shooting",  "StartingInitialConditions" -> {\[Psi]'[0] == 0., [Theta]'[0] == 0., \[Phi]'[0] == 0.}}` we can start but can't finish to compute since there is a problem with stiff system as well.

Comment: Yes you are right.  I tried shooting from starting point in one attempt and from end point in another trial with function-derivative combination but I couldnt get the system solved. Will it be helpful if I converted the 2nd order 3 equation system to 1st order 6 equation system? And if so is there a way to do it in Mathematica ?

Comment: First check that you system is correct. In common case we define rotational matrix `S` as follows  `R1 = RotationMatrix[-\[Psi][s], {0, 0, 1}]; R2 = RotationMatrix[-\[Theta][s], {0, 1, 0}]; R3 = RotationMatrix[-\[Phi][s], {0, 0, 1}]; S = R3 . R2 . R1;` .  Consequently,  the director basis by Euler angles connected to the orthonormal Cartesian basis as $d_i=\sum_{j=1}^3 S_{i j}e_j$.

Comment: Could you compare your system with equations (21) in this paper https://sites.ifi.unicamp.br/aguiar/files/2014/01/bvp.pdf ?

Comment: Hi Alex !  I made mistakes in curvature expression and equilibrium equations. I got it to work after I corrected those.  Thank you for the help ! If anyone is interested I have the working code and results [here.](https://github.com/divesh04/Mathematica/blob/f429a806842799e10162fa7f9d3acee031eb7bb5/hw4_q1_v5_code.pdf) Could the moderators please close this  question as resolved?